# Is it right code or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone Development.
here is my code :

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image ImageKey:(NSObject *)imageKey
{

    NSNumber *number=(NSNumber*)imageKey;
    int num=[number intValue];
        UIScrollView *scrollViewFamily=(UIScrollView*)[scrollViewProfile viewWithTag:6];
        UIButton *btnPhoto=(UIButton*)[scrollViewFamily viewWithTag:num];
        [btnPhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        Photo *aPhoto= [appData.CurrentUser.familyListarray objectAtIndex:num-1000];
        aPhoto.photoImg=image;
 }
```

scrollview retainCount is 3,for button 2 and aPhoto for 1.
now my question is that is it right to write ?if yes then how to release these objects?
help me.Thanking you...

Comment: If you are new to iPhone development and this is a new project, you should use ARC and don't care about retaining/releasing objects.

Comment: its already developed and now i have to check memory leak...and its non-arc project

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code;  method name and arguments, the various random unnecessary casts, the seeming use of a numeric index named "key", etc... Ignore `retainCount`, it is useless.  I would suggest diving into a relatively introductory iOS dev guide and then re-consider this code.

Comment: then please help me...give me guide line...

Comment: Your title is VERY vague

Answer (score -4, accepted):

All lines are pointer to a memory resource, so no memory leak. You have to release memory when you alloc it, to do that use "autorelease", it will make your life easier.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: this is not a mistake, because you don't alloc anything. Your code is perfect.

Comment: This answer makes no sense;  moving the cast from outside to inside the method call expression *changes absolutely nothing*.

Comment: I know, I did an error with a previous answer and ask to remove. I preferred to leave this text like a "suggestion" instead, waiting for user to remove accepted mark because i can't delete accepted answers. I did a mistake during reading.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to us ARC and then you don't have to worry about memory management. If you still want to do it manually, then take this advice [straight from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) regarding retainCount:

> Important This method is typically of no value in debugging memory
>   management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have
>   retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the
>   same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred
>   releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful
>   information from this method. To understand the fundamental rules of
>   memory management that you must abide by, read “Memory Management
>   Rules”. To diagnose memory management problems, use a suitable tool:
>   The LLVM/Clang Static analyzer can typically find memory management
>   problems even before you run your program. The Object Alloc instrument
>   in the Instruments application (see Instruments User Guide) can track
>   object allocation and destruction. Shark (see Shark User Guide) also
>   profiles memory allocations (amongst numerous other aspects of your
>   program).